# scroll infinito com msg ao chegar no final dos resultados

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, rolamento

estou iniciando agora em javascript e ajax entao tem muita coisa que ainda tenho duvida

eu criei um sistema de scroll infinito mas oque nao estou sabendo criar é:

quando chegar ao final da coluna ou ( nao existir mais nada para ser mostrado )

gosta que o ajax incluise um arquivo php onde por exemplo, estara uma div footer com os dados do site

eu ate consigo mostrar uma msg no final mas a msg fica repitindo toda vez que eu tento desser mais a janela

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

var win = $(window);

```
// Each time the user scrolls
win.scroll(function() {
    // End of the document reached?
    if ($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()) {
        $('#loading').show();

        var id = $(".tm:last").attr("id");
        var cat = $(".tm").attr("cat");


        $.ajax({
            url: 'load2.php?id='+id+'&cat='+cat,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(html) {

                if(html){ 
                $('#posts').append(html);
                $('#loading').hide();
                }else{ 

                 ---- aqui que esta a treta !!! ----     
                $('#posts').append("<center><h1 style='color:red'>End of countries !!!!!!!</h1></center>");
                }

            }
        });



    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra não repetir a mensagem basta você checar se já inseriu a mensagem antes. De preferência antes de chamar o ajax, pra economizar recursos.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var win = $(window);

// Each time the user scrolls
win.scroll(function() {
    // End of the document reached?
    if ($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()) {
        $('#loading').show();

        var id = $(".tm:last").attr("id");
        var cat = $(".tm").attr("cat");

        // Se já temos uma div com a classe "fim", nem chama o ajax de novo
        if ( $('.fim').length > 0 ) {
           $('#loading').hide();
           return false; 
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: 'load2.php?id='+id+'&cat='+cat,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(html) {

                if(html){ 
                $('#posts').append(html);
                $('#loading').hide();
                }else{ 

                 // coloque uma classe "fim" na mensagem     
                $('#posts').append("<div class='fim'><h1 style='color:red'>End of countries !!!!!!!</h1></div>");
                }

            }
        });



    }
});
```

Comment: perfeito amigo , funcionou corretamente !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: agradeço por ter me ajuda com essa duvida amigo , muito obrigado mesmo

Comment: ricardo , eu deveria ter me empresado melhor na pergunta , a solução que vc me deu e exatamente oque eu presisava , mas ao inves de mostrar a msg , o apende deveria incluir um arquivo php com o html do footer , eu esqueci de colocar isso na duvida a cima :/

Comment: @JonnysJ. não tem como você inserir um arquivo php ali, porque quando o javascript roda o trabalho do servidor já está feito. O que você pode fazer é retornar o conteúdo que viria nesse php na função ali do `load.php` que retorna a resposta do Ajax. Aí ao invés de checar se `html` está vazio você faz um teste pra saber qual conteudo ele tem. E se não for posts você insere ali no `append()` deu pra entender?

Comment: bom foi exatamente oq fiz mas nao funcionou

Comment: var arq = '<div class="fim"><h1 style="color:red">End of countries !!!!!!!</h1><br><?php include_once "content/layout/footer.php"; ?></div>';
                $('#fot').append(arq);
    alert(arq);

Comment: eu achei que ele iria inserir o dodigo html na pagina , entao quando ele inserisse o codigo , ai puxaria o arquivo php com o codigo do footer

Comment: não vai funcionar. Quando o javascript roda a resposta do ajax já é tarde demais pra usar qualquer função do PHP. Suas opções são colocar o código HTML escrito dentro do javascript ou retornar esse código junto com a resposta do ajax.

Comment: entao minha unica solução seria criar o scroll infinito dentro de uma div e ao chegar no final da div , carregasse mais artigos , assim o footer sempre vai estar la certo? e nao vai precisar ser carregado script acima

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165161/scroll-ligado-a-uma-div-no-html-com-javascrip criei um novo topico sobre isso