# scroll ligado a uma div no html com javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, div, rolamento

a função que eu tenho e para me mostrar mais artigos toda vez que chego ao final da pagina ( paginação scroll infinito ) funciona perfeitamente mas tenho uma duvida que nao estou conseguindo resolver, quero carregar mais artigos assim que o scroll chegar da div "footer" ou na div "final" que vem antes do footer em vez de carregar sempre ao final da pagina

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

var win = $(window);

```
// Each time the user scrolls
win.scroll(function() {
    // End of the document reached?
    if ($(document).height() - win.height() == win.scrollTop()) {
        $('#loading').show();

         // Se jรก temos uma div com a classe "fim", nem chama o ajax de novo
    if ( $('.fim').length > 0 ) {
       $('#loading').hide();
       return false; 
    }

        var id = $(".tm:last").attr("id");
        var cat = $(".tm").attr("cat");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'content/layout/art/load2.php?id='+id+'&cat='+cat,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(html) {

            if(html){ 
            $('#posts').append(html);
            $('#loading').hide();
            }else{ 
            $('#posts').append("<div class='fim'><h1 style='color:red'>End of countries !!!!!!!</h1></div>");

            }




            }
        });
    }
});
```

});

a função funciona perfeitmente se eu nao colocar nada no final do codigo , assim a pessoa chega ao fim da tela , a msg e exibida que nao existe mais nada para ser carregado, mas como expliquei acima , preciso que que sempre que chegar a uma determinada div, a função rode e carregue mais anuncios ou eu crio uma div global onde os anuncios sao carregados dentro dela e quando chegar ao final dessa div ai sim carregue o codigo inserindo mais anuncios detro dela

Comment: Coloca também o código do servidor, onde você responde com mais artigos.

Comment: qual seria o motivo ricardo? pq é um codigo extremamente extenso tem 200 linhas de codigo rss

Comment: mas tudo isso e sempre jogado dentro da div #posts

Comment: a div #posts fica no meio, entre a div do menu superior e antes da div do footer